# Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'DeviceIdentifier' while uploading in firebase firestore. in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to save a device bluetooth information like id and name and etc.
When I want to save them in Firestore, I face this error.
And I have no DeviceIdentifier in my code.

```
addBluetoothInfo(var id, var name, var type, var isDiscoveringServices,
      var services) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = Map();
    map['id'] = id;
    map['name'] = name;
    map['type'] = type;
    map['isDiscoveringServices'] = isDiscoveringServices;
    map['services'] = services;

    await bluetoothRef.add(map).then((value) => print(value)).whenComplete(
      () {
        print('done');
      },
    );
  }
```